# Android emulator not showing all of my applications

Tags: android, emulation

I have 3 projects in Eclipse and I cannot understand why the Android emulator is not showing up the 3rd application.

When I run it I see the following in the **console window:**

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing kokas.exercise.xml.ReadingXMLActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD2.33'
Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD2.33'
New emulator found: emulator-5554
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

---

**XML manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kokas.exercise.xml"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ReadingXMLActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Is there anything else to check? My machine is running Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Did you slide your emulator screen to the right to see if there are any more applications that you _may_ have ignored?

Answer (score 0):

as per your logs your application is not still launched successfully yet..

```
Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched
```

you can confirm this in DDMS under "Device" tab if there your application package name exits in running process?.....

as in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

and if possible put this in manifest

in application tag  android:debuggable="true"

Comment: Under the Device tab I see 3 columns. First one is called "emulator-5554[AVD2.33]", second one is"Online" and third is "AVD2.33". Under the 1st column I see 15 cells, 11 of them with questions marks, the last 4 have values "com.android.protips","com.android.launcher", "system_process", "com.android.deskclock".

The cells under the other 2 columns have numbers as values.

Answer (score 0):

If I ever have problems like this, I do adb uninstall on my project and reinstall it.

Try this

```
adb uninstall kokas.exercise.xml.ReadingXMLActivity
```

then reinstall the application through eclipse.

Also, are you positive the emulator is of a version newer or equal to the one the application is using?

Comment: I tried it and it just gives me "- waiting for device -" ..and it hangs like this forever. 
How do I check the versions of the emulator and application?

Comment: Do you have the emulator running? It should be visible in the device manager. The version is probably fine, it wouldn't let you install if it was bad. Load the emulator and uninstall the app and try and reinstall it. Use the adb command, or go to settings > manage applications and install it that way.

Comment: I have it running. Under "manage applications" I see no ReadingXMLActivity application. While it is running I run the command, it gives me a "failure". Maybe I should just delete the f.... thing and re-create it.